# Cannot convert value of type 'Model' to expected argument type 'Data'

Tags: swift, swiftui, cloudinary

I'm trying to set up a function to capture the response from an API request and map it to a Model once the result hits.

I'm getting this error on the "data" in the "let "cloudinaryResponse" line":  **Cannot convert value of type 'CLDUploadResult' to expected argument type 'Data'**.

The function works fine if I don't do anything with the result.  The result that's returned is of Model type "CloudinaryUploadResponse" so I know it'll match.

```
    private func uploadPhoto(image: UIImage){
        let config = CLDConfiguration(cloudName: "my_sample_cloud", secure: false)
        let cloudinary = CLDCloudinary(configuration: config)
        
        if let image = image.pngData() {
            cloudinary.createUploader().upload(
                data: image, uploadPreset: "my_sample_preset") { progress in
                  print(progress)
            } completionHandler: { result, error in
                
                guard let data = result else { return }
                do {
                 let cloudinaryResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(CloudinaryUploadResponse.self, from: data)
                 print(cloudinaryResponse)
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

I get the same error if I replace "data" with CLDUploadResult

Here's the model I'm trying to map the result to:

```
struct CloudinaryUploadResponse: Codable {
    let assetID, publicID: String
    let version: Int
    let versionID, signature: String
    let width, height: Int
    let format, resourceType: String
    let createdAt: Date
    let tags: [String]
    let bytes: Int
    let type, etag: String
    let placeholder: Bool
    let url: String
    let secureURL: String
    let accessMode: String
    let existing: Bool
    let originalFilename: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case assetID = "asset_id"
        case publicID = "public_id"
        case version
        case versionID = "version_id"
        case signature, width, height, format
        case resourceType = "resource_type"
        case createdAt = "created_at"
        case tags, bytes, type, etag, placeholder, url
        case secureURL = "secure_url"
        case accessMode = "access_mode"
        case existing
        case originalFilename = "original_filename"
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't make any sense. What happens if you `print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "nil")`?

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of your error?

Comment: Sounds like data is *already* of the type CloudinaryUploadResponse and doesn’t need to be decoded. What’s the function signature of upload?

Comment: @jnpdx that's what I'm thinking.  I'm going to work with that object now and see what I can do.

Comment: I think the data you get back in the `result` is of type optional `CLDUploadResult`, there is no need to decode it.
 Use it directly:   `if let response = result { print("\(response.publicId)") }`

Comment: @jnpdx and @ workingdog you were both correct

Comment: just to clarify my comment. You are getting a Cloudinary `CLDUploadResult` in the response, not your `CloudinaryUploadResponse`.

Comment: @workingdog yes, exactly.